# sorting numeric hash keys separated by hyphen

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, key

I have a hash like this

```
my %hash = (
            '2011-49' => 'data1',
            '2011-100' => 'data2',
            '2009-22' => 'data3',
            '2011-11' => 'data4',
            '4323' => 'data5',
            '2354' => 'data6',
            '423532-2' => 'data7'
           );
```

**How to sort hash keys** so that it will sort on the basis of first number then second number showing following output.

```
my %hash = (
            '2009-22' => 'data3',
            '2011-11' => 'data4',
            '2011-49' => 'data1',
            '2011-100' => 'data2',
            '2354' => 'data6',
            '4323' => 'data5',
            '423532-2' => 'data7'
           );
```

I pushed all keys in an array & sorted using
`Sort::Naturally qw(nsort ncmp)` But it doesn't work.

Comment: You cannot sort a hash, hashes do not store the order of their keys. You can sort the keys and put them in an array, though.

Comment: @TLP I did the same thing by putting in the array n sorting

Comment: So then your question is not how to sort a hash, but how to sort the keys.

Comment: Yes I pointed that in my question.

Comment: Yes, but you showed the sorted keys as stored in the hash. Which is not possible. So I just wanted to clarify that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you cannot sort a hash, because a hash does not retain the order of its keys. You can, however, sort its keys and store them in something that does retain order, like an array. For that purpose, we can use a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
my @sorted_keys = map $_->[0],                           # 3)
                  sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] ||          
                         $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] }           # 2)
                  map { [ $_, /(\d+)/g ] } keys %hash;   # 1)
```

From the end, we 1) first store the original string, plus the first and second number inside an anonymous array ref. The result is a list of array refs -- a cache -- which we 2) pass on to `sort`, where they are sorted based first on the first number, and if they are the same, on the second. This is achieved by using `||` inside the `sort` code block. Lastly we 3) restore the original string and discard the array refs.

Comment: Can you please explain how Schwartzian transform works? I read wikipedia already but can't understand coding part.

Comment: It is explained in the answer. It is not important to use it here, but it makes the code more clean, IMO. Basically, it is a means to use a cache to avoid repeating expensive operations during a sort. You store the numbers to use in the sort in a list of arrays, do the sort, then restore the original strings.

Comment: Last edit clear the picture about Schwartzian transform.

Answer (score 1):

You've already gotten a good answer, but thought I would weigh in with Sort::Versions.  This seems to handle these kinds of operations a bit better than Sort::Naturally:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Sort::Versions;

my %hash = (
            '2011-49' => 'data1',
            '2011-100' => 'data2',
            '2009-22' => 'data3',
            '2011-11' => 'data4',
            '4323' => 'data5',
            '2354' => 'data6',
            '423532-2' => 'data7'
);

print "$_ => $hash{$_}\n" for ( sort{ versioncmp( $a, $b ) } keys %hash );
```

This will produce the following output:

```
2009-22 => data3
2011-11 => data4
2011-49 => data1
2011-100 => data2
2354 => data6
4323 => data5
423532-2 => data7
```

Of course you could store the sorted values in an array rather than printing them, but I thought this might be more clear to output this way.